# Haskell stack script extra deps

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In a normal stack project, I can add extra-deps in the stack.yaml file:

```
extra-deps:
- text-1.2.2.0
- unm-hip-0.3.1.6
- safe-exceptions-0.1.4.0
- quickcheck-properties-0.1
- time-interval-0.1.1
- time-units-1.0.0
- snowball-1.0.0.1
- dictionaries-0.1.0.0
resolver: lts-8.3

allow-newer: true
```

But how do I do this in a script?

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
    --resolver lts-8.5
    --install-ghc
    runghc
    --package MissingH
    --package process
    --package attoparsec
    --package split
    --package dictionaries
    --package bytestring
-}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply specifying the package versions in the `--package` flags? E.g. `--package MissingH-X.Y.Z`.

Comment: Yes, I get `Plan construction failed.` The `dictionaries` package is not in stackage.

Comment: any update on this ? I was wondering the same

Comment: this works `stack runghc --resolver lts-12.20 --package raven-haskell-0.1.2.0 ./using-sentry.hs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to specify extra packages on the commande line using e.g.

```
stack runghc --resolver lts-12.20 --package raven-haskell-0.1.2.0 ./using-sentry.hs
```

it does not work with shebang style, inside the file AFAICT

Answer (score 3):

When using shebang style, you can (now at least) do `--extra-dep mypackage-1.3.3.7` within the script.

Credit to @lyxia for pointing me to this (and more generally that I should check `stack script --help`).